# Convergence/Divergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

$$\sum\ n{((2/5)^n + n^2)}.$$

I was told this was possible with the limit comparison test, but most examples using LCT are with fractions. Is it still possible to use it and how?

or what is a better way to solve this? I would prefer if it wasnt with Divergence Test

Comment: Is it supposed to be $\frac{n}{(2/5)^2+n^2}$?

Comment: no, but question was updated

Comment: The $n$th term is greater than $n^3.$ What do you think?

Comment: i was confused because series n(2/5)^n does not diverge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general term of the series given by $$u_n=n ((\frac {2}{5})^n+n^2)$$
is equivalent to $n^3$ thus it is divergent.

Comment: i apologize , question was updated

Comment: @mathguy The answer has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

Whether multiplication or division,
the sum diverges.

If multiplication,
obviously,
since individual terms
go to infinity.

If division,
with the terms being
$\dfrac{n}{((2/5)^2 + n^2)}
$,
they are like
$\dfrac1{n}$,
and the sum of this diverges.

Comment: i apologize, question was updated

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can notice that if we define

$$a_n = n \left( \left(\frac{2}{5} \right)^n+n^2 \right)$$ then the limit of $a_n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ is $\infty \neq 0$, so the series has to diverge, since the terms of the series are getting aribtarily large.